Type mismatch: inferred type is OnSuccessListener<ArrayList<myClass?>> but OnSuccessListener<in ArrayList<myClass>!> was expected
I am trying to convert Java code to Kotlin code but in a code segment in particular it seems is not posible to fully convert.
I am getting a Build error:

Type mismatch
Required: OnSuccessListener<in kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* = java.util.ArrayList */!>
Found: OnSuccessListener<java.util.ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder?>>

The code is to retrieve folders in the Google Drive.
I am using:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

And then:
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive

This is the Java code inside a Class:
private static final String TAG = "GoogleDriveService";
private final Executor mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private final Drive mDriveService;

private final String FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
private final String SHEET_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
private final String FOLDER_NAME = "Example_Folder";

public Task<ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder>> getFolderFileList() {

    ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (folderId.isEmpty()){
        Log.e(TAG, "getFolderFileList: folder id not present" );
        isFolderPresent().addOnSuccessListener(id -> folderId=id)
                .addOnFailureListener(exception -> Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't create file.", exception));
    }

    return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
        FileList result = mDriveService.files().list()
                .setQ("mimeType = '" + SHEET_MIME_TYPE + "' and trashed=false and parents = '" + folderId + "' ")
                .setSpaces("drive")
                .execute();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.getFiles().size(); i++) {
            GoogleDriveFileHolder googleDriveFileHolder = new GoogleDriveFileHolder();
            googleDriveFileHolder.setId(result.getFiles().get(i).getId());
            googleDriveFileHolder.setName(result.getFiles().get(i).getName());

            fileList.add(googleDriveFileHolder);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "getFolderFileList: folderFiles: "+fileList );
        return fileList;
    });
}

Using the Java code:
public void getFolderData(View view) {
    if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);

        mDriveServiceHelper.getFolderFileList()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder> result) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: result: "+result.size() );
                        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("fileList", result);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        showMessage("Not able to access Folder data.");
                        Log.e(TAG, "Not able to access Folder data.", e);
                    }
                });
    }
}

Class in Java:
public class GoogleDriveFileHolder implements Parcelable {

private String id;
private String name;

public GoogleDriveFileHolder(){}

private GoogleDriveFileHolder(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(name);
}

public static final Creator<GoogleDriveFileHolder> CREATOR
        = new Creator<GoogleDriveFileHolder>() {
    public GoogleDriveFileHolder createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new GoogleDriveFileHolder(in);
    }

    public GoogleDriveFileHolder[] newArray(int size) {
        return new GoogleDriveFileHolder[size];
    }
};

}
This is the translated code to Kotlin:
private val mExecutor: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
private val mDriveService: Drive = driveService

private val FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
private val SHEET_MIME_TYPE =
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
private val FOLDER_NAME = "Example_Folder"


val getFolderFileList: Task<java.util.ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder>>
    /**
     * Get all the file present in the user's My Drive Folder.
     */
    get() {
        val fileList = java.util.ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder>()

        if (folderId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getFolderFileList: folder id not present")
            isFolderPresent.addOnSuccessListener { id: String -> folderId = id }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception? ->
                    Log.e(
                        TAG,
                        "Couldn't create file.",
                        exception
                    )
                }
        }

        return Tasks.call(mExecutor) {
            val result: FileList = mDriveService.files().list()
                .setQ("mimeType = '$SHEET_MIME_TYPE' and trashed=false and parents = '$folderId' ")
                .setSpaces("drive")
                .execute()
            for (i in result.files.indices) {
                val googleDriveFileHolder = GoogleDriveFileHolder()
                googleDriveFileHolder.id = result.files[i].id
                googleDriveFileHolder.name = result.files[i].name

                fileList.add(googleDriveFileHolder)
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "getFolderFileList: folderFiles: $fileList")
            fileList
        }
    }

This is using the code in Kotlin:
fun getFolderData(view: View?) {
    if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
        val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)

        ////// Below line code has the build error:
        //// Type mismatch: inferred type is OnSuccessListener<ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder?>> but OnSuccessListener<in ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder>!> was expected

        mDriveServiceHelper!!.getFolderFileList
            .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder?>> { result ->
                Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: result: " + result.size)
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("fileList", result)
                startActivity(intent)
            })
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                showMessage("Not able to access Folder data.")
                Log.e(TAG, "Not able to access Folder data.", e)
            }
    }
}

Class in Kotlin:
class GoogleDriveFileHolder : Parcelable {
var id: String? = null
var name: String? = null

constructor()

private constructor(`in`: Parcel) {
    id = `in`.readString()
    name = `in`.readString()
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    dest.writeString(id)
    dest.writeString(name)
}

companion object CREATOR : Creator<GoogleDriveFileHolder> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): GoogleDriveFileHolder {
        return GoogleDriveFileHolder(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<GoogleDriveFileHolder?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}

}
The Build error:
Type mismatch: inferred type is OnSuccessListener<ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder?>> but OnSuccessListener<in ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder>!> was expected

///// Originally the error was as below but I qualified the ArrayList to java.util.ArrayList :
Type mismatch: inferred type is OnSuccessListener<java.util.ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder?>> but OnSuccessListener<in kotlin.collections.ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder> /* = java.util.ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder> */!> was expected


Here are the steps to resolve this:

Make GoogleDriveFileHolder Non-Nullable in the Task:
Ensure that the GoogleDriveFileHolder instances in the fileList are non-nullable. This can be achieved by explicitly specifying the type as non-nullable when creating the Task and handling it accordingly.

Update the getFolderFileList Property
Change the getFolderFileList property to ensure the list does not contain nullable types. You can do this by specifying the type as ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder> instead of ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder?>.


Here is the updated Kotlin code:
private val mExecutor: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
private val mDriveService: Drive = driveService

private val FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
private val SHEET_MIME_TYPE =
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
private val FOLDER_NAME = "Example_Folder"

val getFolderFileList: Task<ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder>>
    get() {
        val fileList = ArrayList<GoogleDriveFileHolder>()

    if (folderId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getFolderFileList: folder id not present")
        isFolderPresent.addOnSuccessListener { id: String -> folderId = 
        id }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception? ->
                Log.e(
                    TAG,
                    "Couldn't create file.",
                    exception
                )
            }
    }

    return Tasks.call(mExecutor) {
        val result: FileList = mDriveService.files().list()
            .setQ("mimeType = '$SHEET_MIME_TYPE' and trashed=false and 
             parents = '$folderId' ")
            .setSpaces("drive")
            .execute()
        for (i in result.files.indices) {
            val googleDriveFileHolder = GoogleDriveFileHolder()
            googleDriveFileHolder.id = result.files[i].id
            googleDriveFileHolder.name = result.files[i].name

            fileList.add(googleDriveFileHolder)
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "getFolderFileList: folderFiles: $fileList")
        fileList
    }
}

fun getFolderData(view: View?) {
    if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
        val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)

        mDriveServiceHelper!!.getFolderFileList
            .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener { result ->
                Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: result: " + result.size)
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("fileList", result)
            startActivity(intent)
        })
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            showMessage("Not able to access Folder data.")
            Log.e(TAG, "Not able to access Folder data.", e)
        }
   }
}



Ensure Non-Nullable Type in GoogleDriveFileHolder :
In your GoogleDriveFileHolder class, ensure that the properties id and name are non-nullable if they are not supposed to be null:

class GoogleDriveFileHolder : Parcelable {
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""

    constructor()

    private constructor(parcel: Parcel) {
        id = parcel.readString() ?: ""
        name = parcel.readString() ?: ""
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeString(id)
        dest.writeString(name)
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<GoogleDriveFileHolder> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): GoogleDriveFileHolder {
            return GoogleDriveFileHolder(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<GoogleDriveFileHolder?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}


As far as to make the code Build error free this solution works. Thanks. I hope it works when executing.

After testing the code it works nicely. Thanks again!

I’m guessing the listener is a functional interface, so you can just use a lambda and not worry about having to explicitly describe the generic types:
.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
    Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: result: "+result.size() )
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("fileList", result)
    startActivity(intent)
}

